# Redirect non-www to www with .htaccess affecting pagespeed score

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting my web page from non-ww to www using this htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it degrades my pagespeed point for about 6 points for *Avoid landing page redirects* reason.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried only testing the `www.` address?

Comment: You could do a redirect at the DNS level instead. Also, why are you redirecting to www anyways?

Comment: @NathanTuggy ok, I found the pagespeed result page giving the different score for my www and non-www page. thanks!

Comment: @BrokenBinary does the DNS level redirect is better than htaccess solution from the seo perspective?

Comment: I don't know about the SEO perspective, but it will be a little bit faster than a redirect in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because this redirect is being triggered like so

request (mywebsite.com) -> Response (redirect to www.) -> request (www.mywebsite.com) -> response

If you directly test www.mywebsite.com those two redirect steps will be avoided and your page speed score will increase.

Comment: Hmm ok, I found the pagespeed result page giving the different score for my www and non-www page. 
Does this htaccess redirect practice is good from both of technical and seo perspective? Shoud I use redirect from dns level?

Comment: Both ways will lower your page speed score purely because there is an added redirect before the user can see your page.  Best case would be to avoid the redirect entirely and just allow users to use non www.  If that isn't possible just get over the page speed score :P

Comment: For a reason I can't leave both of www and non-www accessible. Is there any other solution for redirect without using htaccess (nor js, html meta)?